# interacting python and abaqus

Tags: python, abaqus

I need for an algorithm to update an input file, I found out that I can modify a .py file and run it in abaqus.

But because of the process is necessary to automatize, I'm trying to open a script and run it in abaqus

I tried this: os.system('abaqus cae script=C:\Users\Samuel\abaqus-1\script1.py')

```
import os
import subprocess


HERE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


def create_script(name):
    path = os.path.join(HERE, 'abaqus-1', name)
    return path


name = 'script1.py'
script_path = create_script(name)
print (script_path)


args = ['abaqus', 'cae', 'script={0}'.format(script_path)]
print (args)
p = subprocess.Popen(args) # Success!
print(p.communicate())
```

this works on the cmd dos windows but doesn’t work on python, if anyone can help me I would appreciate it

error

```
['abaqus', 'cae', 'script=C:\\Users\\Samuel\\abaqus-1\\script1.py']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 89, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Users/Samuel/prueba control.py", line 28, in <module>
    p = subprocess.Popen(args) # Success!
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: For a start you need to post why it does not work on python.  "does not work" is a pretty bad error description.

Comment: Maybe have a look at subprocess: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess

Comment: you might try `noGUI=script.py`, but really "doesnt work" is far too vague

Comment: You need to pass full path to launched binary. Since you're not running it via shell, you cannot rely on shell ability to look up for binaries in PATH environment variable.

Comment: noGUI generates the same error

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski , sorry I don’t understand I have only worked with python or righting this type of codes for a few weeks, I'm a Civil engineer my technical knowledge is a bit limited

Comment: `abaqus` -> `/full/path/to/abacus`

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski thank you so much  args = ['C:\\SIMULIA\\Abaqus\\Commands\\abaqus.bat', 'cae', 'script={0}'.format(script_path)] finally it works

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this sentence is incorrect -

```
os.system('abaqus cae script=C:\Users\Samuel\abaqus-1\script1.py')
```

You have to run a python script in Abaqus using the command

```
abaqus cae noGUI=nameOfScript.py
```

So in your case,

```
os.system('abaqus cae noGUI=C:\\Users\\Samuel\\abaqus-1\\script1.py')
```

I am not sure about the '\' since I usually open abaqus in the same folder where I have my python scripts.